# Enum for index signature parameter type in Typescript

Tags: enums, typescript

My goal is to have an object with attributes part of a typescript string enum.

```
type PARAM = "long-parameter" | "long-parameter2";

const PARAM = {
    param1: "long-parameter" as PARAM,
    param2: "long-parameter2" as PARAM,
}

var f = function(params:{[id:PARAM]:number}){}

f({ //must be valid
    [PARAM.param1]:1,
});

f({ //should display error
    "asdas":1
});
```

The problem is that `var f = function(params:{[id:PARAM]:number}){}` returns the error `An index signature parameter type must be string or number.`

Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for an index signature *must be a string or a number*. This just because of how JavaScript works (everything is converted to a `string` in an object member lookup).

If you know the names of the member you should really declare them up front. This is shown below:

```
type PARAM = "long-parameter" | "long-parameter2";

const PARAM = {
    param1: "long-parameter" as PARAM,
    param2: "long-parameter2" as PARAM,
}

var f = function(params: { "long-parameter"?: PARAM, "long-parameter2"?: PARAM }) { }

f({ //must be valid
    [PARAM.param1]: 1,
});

f({ //should display error
    "asdas": 1
});
```

Tested with [alm](http://alm.tools/):

[image]

Comment: How does the valid assignment work - `1` is not the string value `long-parameter` or `long-parameter2` but the values for the interface are set to `PARAM` ... why does `f({[PARAM.param1]: 1})` successfully compile?